# Why does update discards information in the UpdateReport in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I was looking into make some evictions fatal on sbt builds by changing the `update` task. I quickly found that the `UpdateReport` returned by it contains no eviction information. I looked at the source code then, and noticed that `evicted` calls `updateFull`, whose only difference to `update` is changing two flags in a downstream call, which result in that information *not* being discarded.

It's something done very explicitly, and the sole distinction between it and `updateFull`, both being one-liners calling the same method. And, on the other hand, I see no purpose in doing so. Replacing `update` with `updateFull` would allow me to tackle my stuff on it, but I worry it might have unforeseen consequences.

I tried replacing `update` with `updateFull` and ran a build successfully, but that doesn't prove anything. So I'm wondering why does `update` discard this information?